# filter numbers that are greater than or equal to a number(that number is omitted) and then delete them?

Tags: javascript

This question will sound strange, but I have been with this blocker for a long time. I'm trying to go through an array that has a series of numbers in string (I'm simulating my idea scenario, this also seems weird), then in a loop I want to get the index of the numbers in my object that are greater than or equal to 75 for later eliminate the elements that are not.

The output should be: `75` and `100`. but for some reason the output is `100`. What am I doing wrong? I am even eliminating in reverse because if I eliminate within the lopp I would have problems.

```
number="75";
aIndex=[];
aData=
[
  {
    "number":"75"
  },
  {
    "number":"50",
  },
  {
    "number":"100"
  }
];

for(var i in aData){
  let data=parseInt(aData[i].number);
  let number=parseInt("75");
  console.log(data);
  console.log(number);
  console.log(data <=number)
  if(data<=number){
    console.log(data , "<=", number)
    let index=aData.indexOf(aData[i]);
    aIndex.push(index);
    console.log("index",index);
  }
}

for(var n = aIndex.length -1; n >= 0 ; n--){
 aData.splice(aIndex[n], 1);
}    
console.log(aData);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/omeka4q3/

Comment: I think it's `i.number` rather than `aData[i].number`

Comment: @Jay No, `i` is the *property name* being iterated over (since this is an array, `'0'`, `'1'`, etc)

Comment: Interesting. I would've thought it referenced a single element of the array - an object in this case. Quite counter intuitive

Answer (score 1):

You currently test if `data<=number`, and if so, `push` the index to `aIndex` and later splice out that index. If you want to *keep* numbers that are equal, use `<` instead.

```js
number="75";
aIndex=[];
aData=
[
  {
    "number":"75"
  },
  {
    "number":"50",
  },
  {
    "number":"100"
  }
];

for(var i in aData){
  let data=parseInt(aData[i].number);
  let number=parseInt("75");
  console.log(data);
  console.log(number);
  console.log(data <number)
  if(data<=number){
    console.log(data , "<=", number)
    let index=aData.indexOf(aData[i]);
    aIndex.push(index);
    console.log("index",index);
  }
}

for(var n = aIndex.length -1; n >= 0 ; n--){
 aData.splice(aIndex[n], 1);
}    
console.log(aData);
```

Or, you could use `filter` instead of manually `splice`ing, which can be tedious and error-prone:

```js
const aData = [{
    "number": "75"
  },
  {
    "number": "50",
  },
  {
    "number": "100"
  }
];
const aDataFiltered = aData.filter(({ number }) => Number(number) >= 75);
console.log(aDataFiltered);
```

Comment: Your test was `data<=number`, but you want to *include* numbers that are equal or greater than (use `<` instead)

Comment: <= it means "equal or greater than" and <  "great than"  no?

Comment: No, `<=` means `less than or equal to`, just like `<` means `less than`. `3 < 5 === true`

Comment: "Your test was data<=number, but you want to include numbers that are equal or greater than (use < instead) " your comment is correct?

Comment: Yes, because your logic was, when that test is passed, remove that index from the array (eventually)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the result you expect:

```js
let aData = [
  {number: "75"},
  {number: "50"},
  {number: "100"}
];

let filtered = aData.reduce((acc, {number}) => {
  number = Number(number);
  if(number >= 75){
    acc.push(number);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```